# Android AVD not linking or diplaying app

Tags: android, eclipse, testing, android-emulator, genymotion

Hello people of Stack Overflow!

I've been trying to create my first app for a while now using eclipse.

I understand how to create the layout in XML. I understand Java enough to do build simple java applications and work with packages and such.

I've been following this tutorial series and have come to a point where i need to test the app.
[youtube]watch?v=B-HL6QTdOXs
** sorry: not enough rep to make three links **

This is where the trouble is - testing. The emulator from AVD doesn't show my app's icon anywhere in the menu. I have also tried Genymotion, and the same issue occurs.

As far as I know, all of the paths and uri's are correct to link everything up, but it just won't 
show.

The directory structure containing AVD Manager and SDK Manager are both located directly on the C drive.
My eclipse workspace is under my user's folder.

When I go to run it as an android application, the option doesn't appear sometimes, but once I clean the project, the button appears again.

Below are some screen-captures I took and uploaded to imgur. I hope somebody can help me.

~ imgur album ~

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZsuv.jpg

~ glewinfo paste ~ 
http://pastebin.com/1gUJ6xDb

Thanks for the attention! :)

I'm willing to try Android Studio as well, but eclipse I am accustomed to from school.

Comment: **UPDATE**: Android Studio is working. This thread may help somebody in the future, so it's here. If you think it should be deleted, i will do the honors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it whatcmade the problem but you dont have any setContentView there.
Your app will not show any xmlfile or even a view.

Make sense that your app will not show anything but i dont think thatvit will cause it to disapear (if icunderstood correctly)

Try fix it and if it does not work please show me your androidManifest.xml file

Comment: thanks for the feedback. i added the line and now its having trouble with R.java. It's saying it shouldn't be imported, so I looked for an example. 

http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/apps-for-android/DivideAndConquer/src/com/google/android/divideandconquer/R.java.shtml

This says it's an autogenerated file. I guess this means I have to start over. I don't remember deleting it, though I probably did. I'll post a paste here of my manifest file. 

http://pastebin.com/kffKQMcY

this is the line i added
"
setContentView(R.layout.main);
"